# `How to move fragment from one container to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two containers :contaner1 and container2. In container1 i have Fragment1 and i replaced it with Fragment2. My purpose is to to present Fragment1 in container1 and Fragment in container2. I want to take Feagment2 from container and put it into container2.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container1, Fragment2)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit();
```

Comment: You want to apply drag and drop feature or just replace ?

Comment: In the code you can see that i replaced Fragment1 with Fragment2 in container1. Then i  want to take fragment2 from container1 and put this fragment into container2.